# change relation records Laravel5.2

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have the following problem, I have two models Level and Class: Level has the relation **classes()** ,then after getting level classes :

```
$level->classes
```

the data returned is like this: 
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "class 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "class 2"
    }
now I want to discard class 2 , I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
        $ids=[2];
        $classes=$level->classes;

        $classes=$classes->whereIn('id',$ids);

        $level->classes=$classes;
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You want to delete the record or only return the results in the $ids array?

Comment: I want to return the results in the $ids array

Comment: I think you might need a `->get()` on that `whereIn`. It would be helpful to explain what "it doesn't work" means exactly. What was the issue?

Comment: $classes has the result that I want  but when i tried to update the level classes it always keep the original data

Comment: Just to understand, you want to discard the id:2 but your `$ids=[2]` in `whereIn()` method will return the class with `id = 2`. Isn't it ?

Comment: Incase you want to remove the classes with ids present in `$ids` use `whereNotIn()` method instead of `whereIn()`

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use eager loading to accomplish what you want. If you just want one Level you'd have to add constraint for that as well after the ')' and before the '->get();'

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

```
$ids = [2];

$levels = Level::with(
    [
        'classes' => function ($query) use ($ids) {
            $query->whereIn('id', $ids);
        }
    ]
)->get();
```

Comment: to be more specific, I have many levels with many classes for each level and then I have the ids for each level to discard ? in my case this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `$level->classes()->whereIn('id', $ids)->get()`.

This will return an instance of Relation class, which has all the methods as a normal query builder.